# NPAPI Plugin doesn't work well on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, npapi

I tried both `npapi` and `firebreath`, but all of them only work well on Firefox, and easily stuck on Chrome . the function I wrote in plugin is the `simplist "return 0;"`. i processed the Xemd case.

```
NPError NPP_GetValue(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value)

{
  ...
  switch (variable) {

  case NPPVpluginNeedsXEmbed:
    *((BOOL*)value) = TRUE;
...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all of them only work well on Firefox, and easily stuck on Chrome"?

Comment: What version of Firefox, and Chrome, are you trying to use NPAPI with?

Comment: Thank you very much.I use the versions old enough to support npapi:firefox 40, chrome 36 and 41.My prblem is :on the firefox,javescript can invoke the functions exported by plugin easily,but on chrome,once js invoke the plugin functions,the broswer get stuck , it takes a long time before the invoke finish, and in most cases it never finish,even though the function does nothing but return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I tried with chrome version 22. Higher version may also work.
It's not easy to find such an old version ,I'm afraid my plugin will never be used.-_-||

Comment: I tried more versions,those below  31 (including) are OK,higher versions have the problem. Who can tell me why ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what versions you are using; Chrome discontinued support for NPAPI plugins (supported by FireBreath 1) in 2014; Firefox discontinued support for NPAPI plugins in Firefox 52, though I believe there was a LTS version of firefox 52 which continued to support them for another year and a half (which is likely over by now).

In short, NPAPI is pretty much dead -- the last holdout in generally used browsers is Safari and it's going away with the release of macOS Mojave.

There is a way to write a firebreath 2 plugin and make it work via native messaging but it's a bit of a complicated process and it's not super well documented; you can find information on the firebreath-dev google group and ask clarifying questions there.

Comment: really honored to see your answer, I write the plugin just as something like "plan B" which may not be used but my leader told me just make one in case some customer may ask for. the plugin just export some functions to let the javascript to invoke which are about encrpt and decrypt.My problem is :on the firefox,javescript can invoke the functions easily,but on chrome,once js invoke the plugin functions,the broswer get stuck , it takes a long time before the invoke finish, and mostly it never finish. I tried some simple functions like "return 0;" but it's all the same.

Comment: versions : chrome 36 and 41.